# compere datetime in sqlserver

Tags: mysql, datetime

Im sitting with a little problem..

In my database i have a table that contains 2 dateTimes..

TABLE1 has **turn_time** as a dateTime valued **0000-00-00 23:59:59**

TABLE2 has **last_move** as DateTime valued **2013-09-23 14:20:19**

And i want to calculate in SQL if turn_time + last_move < NOW().

but the result im getting back looks like this:
**40261846333938.000000**

how do i get a simple select back of the current row if turn_time + last_move < NOW() ?

my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM active_games 
        INNER JOIN games 
        ON active_games.fk_games_id = games.games_id 
        INNER JOIN product
        ON active_games.fk_product = product.product_id
        INNER JOIN users
        ON active_games.fk_user_id_turn = users.user_id
        INNER JOIN user_profile 
        ON users.user_id = user_profile.fk_user_id
        WHERE turn_time + last_move < NOW()
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: Is SQL Server involved at all?

Comment: If you add two DateTimes what kind of result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `WHERE` clause instead:

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(turn_time) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_move) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

The documentation for [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) says the following:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Since `NOW()` is being used in a numeric context within your `WHERE` clause, it's returning the numeric value (in the `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format), and attempting to compare them to the DateTime `turn_time + last_move`. Converting everything to a Unix timestamp should allow the comparison to work properly.

Hope this helps!